# Build not added to prereleases on iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store-connect

I have a version of my app with status "prepare for submission" on iTunesConnect. Yesterday, I verified and successfully submitted a binary to iTunesConnect via Xcode 6.0.1. But its been more than 24 hrs and the binary is still not visible in Prerelease section. I want to submit this version immediately. What could be the reason for this behavior and how can I upload a new binary now?
Note: There are already 2 "inactive" builds in prerelease for this version.

Comment: Try reuploading the build. If it fails, that means the build is in iTunes Connect somewhere since you can't upload two with the same build number. If not, it was just some glitch with their system.

Comment: I notice that when i submit via Xcode while I am still on the screen stating prepare for submission and tap on the button to select a binary, I don't see the upload. I always have to go back to some other screen then return and tap on the button again. In the 24 hour period have you left that screen?

Comment: Yes I did signout and then logged in again but the build was not there. However, now after uploading a new build with a new build number 3-4 times I finally have a build added to prerelease section but now its stuck in the "Processing" state.

Comment: Have you changed your bundle id? Apps are grouped together by bundle id, so if you've changed it, it won't be showing up with your existing app.

Comment: So, I finally got the build uploaded and submitted for Review. The problem was with the XCode. Initially, I was using XCode 6.0.1 to upload the build but, upgrading the Xcode to version 6.1.1 solved the problem. I believe its another constraint of the new iTunesConnect.